# Is it OK to have auxiliary methods inside the controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

Sometimes I need to have small auxiliary methods specific for some controller, is it OK to actually have them inside the controller class? My concern is that these methods are not supposed to be routed/reachable through URL.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it is OK. You may either make these methods private, or mark them as `[NonAction]` attribute: in both cases they won't be routed to.